# Divider in listview

Tags: android, listview

In My application i am showing the data from database in list view.List view is like showing 2 columns.Now i want to draw a horizontal line in between this 2 to have a display that 2 columns  are separated.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain seperate xml file for showing list view items, In the List xml file use this horizontal and vertical views in between **textViews**

so for horizontal divider use this code

```
     <View 
          android:id="@+id/View01"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="#2B497B"
        />
```

and for vertical divider

```
         <View 
          android:id="@+id/View02"
          android:layout_width="2dip"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#2B497B"
        />
```

Good luck

Comment: I tried for your code.In that if i try for horizontal view it shpws line between two textview,but if i use vertical divider it shows nothing..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

         <TextView 
             android:padding="2dp"
             android:id="@+id/nameedit"
             android:textSize="15dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:text="@string/search">
        </EditText>
         <View 
          android:id="@+id/View01"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="#2B497B"
        />
<TextView 
             android:id="@+id/header"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:textColor="#fff"
             android:textSize="15dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="@string/reports"/>
        <!-- <ListView android:id="@+id/namelist"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="none">
        </ListView> -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <View 
          android:id="@+id/View02"
          android:layout_width="2dip"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#2B497B"
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/header"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:textColor="#fff"
             android:textSize="15dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="@string/reports"/>
         <View 
          android:id="@+id/View03"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:background="#2B497B"
        />

        <!-- <ListView android:id="@+id/reportslist"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:fadingEdge="none"/> -->
        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/header"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:textColor="#fff"
             android:textSize="15dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="@string/reports"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file where you are defining your listview, add one more parameter for the divider height:

```
       <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@color/listDivider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            style="@style/listBackground" 
            android:id="@+id/list"/>
```

Here "listBackground" is the custom background which I have  defined in my style.xml file. And "listDivider" is the color for divider which I have defined in my color.xml , like this:

```
       <color name="listDivider">#cfcfcf</color>
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh Somani. Its dividing horizontally,but i want to divide it vertically

Comment: well , then you'll have to create an xml file for a listitem(which may contain a lot of things in it like buttons , textviews etc.) and then inflate this xml file into listview. In this xml file just define a view (wherever required) as Ram Kiran has done but with a height= fill_parent and width= 1 dip. that will draw a vertical line.